# Variables inside extensions in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, private

I want to know how the odometer variable behaves in the following example.I mean since its declared within an extension is it private?

```
 //In Car.m
#import "Car.h"
@interface Car ()
@property (readonly) double odometer;
-(BOOL)engineIsWorking;
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables/methods declared in the extension are only visible in the compilation units that they are imported into or declared within.

For example, you could put your extensions in a file called `Car_Private.h`, then `#import "Car_Private.h"` in both `Car.m` (so the `@implementation Car` automatically synthesizes storage and methods) and `Tire.m`.  By doing so, `Tire.m` would effectively have access to `engineIsWorking` and `odometer`.

That is, extensions are only as "private" as you want them to be.   Note that nothing is truly private in Objective-C;  it is only private at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As your are declaring the extension in you `.m` file, and you never `#import` this `.m` file anywhere (you `#import` the `.h`), only the code within the `.m` file has access to this extension.

As stated in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3):

> Class extensions are often used to extend the public interface with additional private methods or properties for use within the implementation of the class itself.

Comment: It isn't a category though; extensions are distinct and different.  Specifically, a category can have an `@implementation` and cannot synthesize `@property`s.  An extension can only extend the `@implementation` (if declared prior to the compilation of the `@implementation` and can also declare synthesized properties, including promoting a readonly property to readwrite.

Comment: Yes, I mixed things up. Thanks for the correction, I edited to prevent  confusing other people reading this too :)